# Separating javascript "classes" or "modules" from View Model with Knockout.js / RequireJs

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, requirejs

I have an app that I'm developing with Knockout and I'm using RequireJs and what I'm trying to do is have certain code available to a number of different pages without having to have the code in more than one file... things like this:

```
    function perPageOption(value, display) {
        this.value = value;
        this.display = display;
    }
```

I have in my page:

`<script data-main="/Scripts/JournalEntriesDetailPage" src="~/Scripts/require.js"></script>`

And the script (JournalEntriesDetailPage):

```
require(['Knockout', 'journalEntiresDetailViewModel', './app/JournalModels', 'domReady'], function (ko, viewModel) {
ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

});

And then in my "journalEntiresDetailViewModel" I have this:

```
//per page options
self.perPageOptions = [new perPageOption(10, 10), new perPageOption(20, 20), new perPageOption(50, 50), new perPageOption(100, 100)];
```

The './app/JournalModels' is where the arrays/classes are located and they come up 'undefined' when I try to use them in any page that I try to "import" them in to. I having a hard time trying to figure this out. I've looked at the examples for multiple page apps on requirejs and they seem way too complicated for what I'm trying to do. I don't understand why "domready" is working when I "require" it, but my file isn't working.

I've also tried this with no success:

```
define(['Knockout'], function (ko) {
    define('EntryType', function () {
    function EntryType(data) {
        this.id = ko.observable(data.ID);
        this.name = ko.observable(data.Name);
        this.color = ko.observable(data.Color);
        this.journaltypeid = ko.observable(data.JournalTypeID);
    }
    return new EntryType();
    });
});
```

and

```
define('EntryType', function () {
    return function EntryType(data) {
        this.id = ko.observable(data.ID);
        this.name = ko.observable(data.Name);
        this.color = ko.observable(data.Color);
        this.journaltypeid = ko.observable(data.JournalTypeID);
    }
});
```

and

```
define(['Knockout'], function (ko) {

return {
    pagePerOption: function(data) {
        this.value = value;
        this.display = display;
    },
    entryType: function(data) {
        this.id = ko.observable(data.ID);
        this.name = ko.observable(data.Name);
        this.color = ko.observable(data.Color);
        this.journaltypeid = ko.observable(data.JournalTypeID);
    }
}
});
```

Comment: I've not done much with them at all, but have you seen [Knockout Components](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-overview.html)?  I think they may go some way to help you here.

Comment: Are you exporting the constructor?

Comment: I hadn't seen that yet, it looks like I might be able to use that for some stuff, but I need things like a re-usable "entry" object that I can use anywhere I want.

Comment: @CrimsonChris I'm kinda new to Javascript and I'm not sure about what you mean. I'm pretty sure that I am NOT.

Comment: Your `perPageOption` has a lowercase initial letter, but your calls using `new` have an uppercase initial letter.

Comment: @RoyJ - I knew someone would mention that... they are the same case in my actual code.

Comment: I think `define` is expecting a function that *returns* what you want to export, which in this case is your constructor function.

Comment: @CrimsonChris - edited to show that I (think?) tried that...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29464274/reloading-reinitializing-refreshing-commonjs-modules

Comment: ps in the end i went with localstorage gives me additional offline capababilty

Comment: `self.perPageOptions = ...` Is that the entire content of your viewmodel script? It doesn't have a define statement in it. I also think that the dependency on JournalModels should be in there, not in your first script. Finally, to my memory (maybe it's changed) domReady should have an exclamation mark after it; since it has different behavior from simply loading and returning a script.

Comment: @Katana314 - there are a lot more lines to the viewmodel, I just didn't think putting ALL of it would help. domready seems to work with or without the ! - I can put a reference in the viewmodel as well and it gets me the same thing - undefined.

Comment: I didn't need to see the whole thing, just wanted to make sure it was actually written in requirejs syntax, and loaded its dependencies that way.

Comment: define(['Knockout', './app/JournalModels'], function (ko, model) {
    return function () { //viewmodel stuff });  ... is how its written. @Katana314

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I thought I tried this before, but this is working now:

Page:

```
    <script data-main="/Scripts/JournalEntriesDetailPage" src="~/Scripts/require.js"></script>
```

Init script (JournalEntriesDetailPage):

```
require(['Knockout', 'journalEntiresDetailViewModel', 'domReady!'], function (ko, viewModel) {
     ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
});
```

View model script (journalEntiresDetailViewModel):

```
define(['Knockout', './app/JournalModels'], function (ko, model) {
return function () {
    //per page options
    self.perPageOptions = [new model.perPageOption(10, 10), new model.perPageOption(20, 20), new model.perPageOption(50, 50), new model.perPageOption(100, 100)];
    //tons of other code
    }
});
```

and the definition in the "models" script (JournalModels):

```
define(['Knockout'], function (ko) {

function _entryType(data) {
    this.id = ko.observable(data.ID);
    this.name = ko.observable(data.Name);
    this.color = ko.observable(data.Color);
    this.journaltypeid = ko.observable(data.JournalTypeID);
}

return {
    entryType: function (data) {
        return new _entryType(data);
    },
    entry: function (data) {
        this.id = ko.observable(data.ID);
        this.createdby = ko.observable(data.CreatedBy);
        var datey = new Date(+data.CreatedDate.match(/\d+/)[0]);
        this.createddate = ko.observable(datey.toLocaleDateString() + " " + datey.toLocaleTimeString());
        this.content = ko.observable(data.Content);
        this.entrytype = ko.observable(new _entryType(data.EntryType));
        this.entrytypename = ko.observable(data.EntryType.Name);
        this.entrytypeid = ko.observable(data.EntryType.ID);
        this.journalid = ko.observable(data.journalid);
    },

    perPageOption: function (value, display) {
        this.value = ko.observable(value);
        this.display = ko.observable(display);
    }
}
});
```

I needed to return the data in the models script, which I thought I tried, but I must have not done the other essential part... which was:

```
define(['Knockout', './app/JournalModels'], function (ko, model) {...
```

... in the view model script so I could use "model" in my view model like "model.pagePerOption". Basically I just had to stumble on the the right combination... because I was trying everything and changing it so much that the two things I needed probably weren't there at the same time until they finally were.

Thanks for the responses... :)

Comment: If you're not using `_entryType` outside `entry`, you don't even have to bother exporting it. `entry` will have access to it because it's in the upper function's scope. With AMD you'd normally load one module per file, so even cleaner would be to separate `perPageOption` (like in your question post) from `entry`, also allowing you to access it as  `perPageOption` in function parameters, instead of as `model.perPageOption`. As for Knockout, components require some getting used to, but they're real great for this kind of things once you do.